# SFTP connection in PHP (not via ssh)

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

after creating a small library to send and receive files via SFTP using **ssh2_sftp** method I've found that the server which I have to connect to has ssh connection **disabled** and I can only connect through SFTP.

The server connection works well under the command line using sftp command, but ssh sends me a *"This service allows sftp connections only."*

So as ssh2_sftp needs a previous ssh connection in order to work, I don't know which library or how to do things in order to connect to a SFTP server with SFTP authentication.

Does phpseclib use a different authentication approach than ssh2_ftp?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh2_ftp()` first? It's not entirely clear from the question whether it was an assumption :) afaik the `ssh2_connect()` establishes a connection without choosing any particular service such as shell or sftp

Comment: "Previous SSH connection" is a wrong term. SSH protocols include *shell* access (which is disabled in your case), SFTP subsystem, port forwarding and more. SFTP doesn't require shell access in vast majority of cases (it can require shell when SFTP itself is not configured right which is not the case for you).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp it's correct in the sense that sftp needs a prior connection to work :)

Comment: Yeah, when using ssh2_ftp it expects a $connection parameter that has to be the result of a ssh2_connect call. In my case this latter one is failing as ssh is not alowwed

Comment: I suggest you learn a little more about sftp, what is really is and especially its relation to ssh. You will be able to answer your question yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% of keyboard-interactive authentications just prompt for a password.  [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), tries submitting the password via keyboard-interactive if password authentication fails.  Example of how to use it:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

// outputs the contents of filename.remote to the screen
echo $sftp->get('filename.remote');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're completely right @arkascha... after a little research I found the reason.

When I was testing my code against my own server, it worked, and against the other server it was failing so I thought it was because ssh shell connection was disabled.

After asking both servers for the allowed auth methods (using ssh2_auth_none), I got what was wrong:

My server:

**[0] => publickey**

**[1] => password**

The other server (the one that was failing):

**[0] => publickey**

**[1] => gssapi-keyex**

**[2] => gssapi-with-mic**

**[3] => keyboard-interactive**

as it doesn't allow password, it is failing. That's it...

I apologize for making you waste your time...Thanks a lot